# Position a widget relative to a centered widget

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a login page. I would like the email/password text fields to be centered within the page, and the button to be 48dp below the last field (and therefore not factored into the calculation of the text fields' centered position).

I cannot figure out how to modify my layout such that the button is not included as a centered element as is currently shown in the screenshot:

[image: Image depicting a mobile login screen. There are text fields for email and password as well as a login button. The elements as a group are all centered within the page]

My code:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Form(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    RoundedTextField(
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    RoundedTextField.password(
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 48,
                    ),
                    PrimaryButton(
                      child: Text('Log In'),
                      onPressed: () => print(null),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I come from the world of Android development where we can just do `constrainTopToBottomOf:@id/passwordField` and I'm not sure if there's really an equivalent in the flex system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution for this use-case is a Column with some Expanded as such:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(),
    someContent,
    Expanded(
      child: someOffsetContent,
    ),
),
```

A more visual example: (the purple is the expanded)

[image]

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple)),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 42,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 42,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 42.0,
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is maintain simmetry with a button that is not displayed nor used:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Form(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Opacity(
                      opacity: 0.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(''),
                        onPressed: null,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 48,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Log In'),
                      onPressed: () => print(null),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as a general case solution. If I add another text field, it now overflows the bottom and I have to start playing with the flex values to fix it. `4/2/4` adds more space between the last field and the button than `4/3/4` for example, and I need there to be 48dp exactly.

Comment: You are right. I have updated my answer with an easier solution.

Comment: Seems a little hacky but it's some out-of-the-(flex)box thinking and gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

kind of a hack, but you can set a height with a media query:

```
double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5;
```

then do this:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Container(
            height: _height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'email@email.com',
                    labelText: 'Email',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            height: _height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'email@email.com',
                    labelText: 'Email',
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 48.0)),
                Text('some button'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```